# Data Validation with an IF formula

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, google-sheets-query, worksheet-function, data-validation

I've got a list of items that I want to include in a Drop Down. Using data validation, all I need to do is add the range and this works. However, the list has various types of data and I want to create a Data Validation that gives options from the given range if the type is correct. Is this possible?

I've added a link to the list. Essentially, let's say for Life providers, I want to have data validation showing all items in the first column IF their type is Life.

[image]

Comment: Related: [Dropdown list based on the result of another cell's dropdown](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/86802/88163)

Answer (score 1):

**yes that is possible. check this example:**

[image]

## Sheet1:

**D20: Data Validation > List of items: `I made a choice,I didn't make a choice`**

**F20: Data Validation > List from a range: `Sheet2!D8:D11`**

## Sheet2:

**D8: `=IF(Sheet1!D20 = B6; QUERY(B8:B11;;-1);IF(Sheet1!D20 = C6; QUERY(C8:C11;;-1);))`**