# Relational dropdown based on database sheet?

Tags: google-sheets

How would one go about implementing a relational dropdown based on a database sheet?

I have made the following example:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1J1hmGlB5pg7k1Q1lh2kdnb6cmgBKsCVC-nz1JfEDOgs/edit#gid=0

Tab "Dropdown" requires the user to choose a value in column A.

Based on this selection, a sub-selection should show as a dropdown on column B.

Values for column A and B should come from a separate sheet called "Database".

I am wondering, can this be achieved with Google Sheets formulas only or does it require a script?

Comment: This could be achieved with Google Sheets formulas.

Comment: Could you give me a hint as to which formulas?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Data Validation with an IF formula](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/118731/data-validation-with-an-if-formula)

Comment: @Tedinoz don't think this will work in my case as the number of rows with dropdowns keeps increasing.

Comment: Yep, I should have seen that. There are many options. Google "google sheets multiple row dependant dropdowns" and see what I mean. Typically formula-based solutions rely on helpers-if that's OK then the @player0 answer to [Multi row dependent dropdown
](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59362275/1330560) is good. For scripts [How do you do dynamic / dependent drop downs in Google Sheets?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21744547/1330560) has been a meeting place for discussing and updating techniques for dynamic dependant dropdowns since 2014. Have a look at the answer (and comments) by Max Makhrov.